# Back-end typescript in monorepo: how to get dependencies for docker?

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a project in a yarn-workspaces monorepo, containing front-end, back-end, and common packages. All in typescript.

Building and running the front end is fine; it uses webpack to create a `dist/` dir that I can deploy.
The back end should be easier, because it's just typescript -> node.js. I can just `tsc` and package the resulting `dist` dir into my docker image... except for the `node_modules` dependencies. How can I get just the needed dependencies into `dist`? I don't want a full-on bundler with all the transpiling and fancy stuff.

Some people use multi-stage docker to create the build (by running `yarn install --production` in the fresh docker build image, so it's not part of the monorepo); that seems like overkill to me, and it seems harder to debug that way because you don't get to run the actual build from your dev machine.

I'd like a tool that produces a working `dist` folder that I can package with docker or any other method. Is there a simple way to get to that?

Answer (score 1):

You can `COPY` whatever you'd like in your Dockerfile.  If your application is already built on your host, then you can just copy in the build artifacts and its runtime dependencies.  For a Node package this might look like

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --production
COPY dist dist/
CMD ["node", "/app/dist/index.js"]
```

Of note, [`yarn install --production`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-production-true-false) avoids copying in anything in the `"devDependencies"` section of your `package.json` file, which would skip things like `tsc` and `webpack`.

(This technique is more common for compiled languages – especially Java Dockerfiles tend to just copy in a built `.jar` or `.war` file – and in very old Docker that pre-dates multi-stage builds.)

Comment: Thanks -- but what I'm after is a way to get to that minimal build on my local. If I do the `yarn install` in the Dockerfile then it'll have everything, not just "tree shaken" actually-used dependencies, right? Do I have to go all the way to using a bundler? (I come from the old C/C++ days where, when you link your app statically, it pulls in only the objs it needs.)

Comment: Or maybe I'm just overthinking things and just copying my app's `package.json` and `.../yarn.lock` to `/tmp`, doing `yarn install --production --modules-folder /path/to/my/app/dist/node_modules` there (so it's not part of a monorepo) is good enough? After all, it's a back-end service, what's a few extra MB between friends?